# Why using jsPDF justify for text keep the word spacing for other texts?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, justify

Program for generating the pdf:

```
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);

doc.setFontSize(14);
doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
doc.text(testText, 30, 30, {maxWidth: 200, align: 'justify'});

doc.text('10 de dezembro', 30, 220, {maxWidth: 200, align: 'left'});

doc.save('testing.pdf');
```

Problem is with the result, by what i see, it keep the last word spacing for the next texts

[Image with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP4Ie.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced the same issue, and to solve it I had to reset the word spacing to the default (`0`) by manually doing `doc.internal.write(0, "Tw")` right after using a justified text (had to look into the source code to find it), so your code would look like this:

```
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);

doc.setFontSize(14);
doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
doc.text(testText, 30, 30, {maxWidth: 200, align: 'justify'});
doc.internal.write(0, "Tw") // <- add this

doc.text('10 de dezembro', 30, 220, {maxWidth: 200, align: 'left'});

doc.save('testing.pdf');
```

Hope this helps.